# Remove Documents and Pictures

Tags: directory

Is there a way to remove the 'documents' and 'pictures' options from my personal folders. I have a work machine that I need to upload some files from but don't want to give that machine the option to access my personal documents and pictures.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Directory Encryption with encfs.

Encfs is an application that allows you to create encrypted directories, any file that is placed in such a directory will be encrypted. To open an encrypted directory you need a correct password.

Please refer to [FolderEncryption](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FolderEncryption) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you already need to have access to that machine to even be able to get files.
There are several methods in doing this...

1. If both have USB use a stick.
2. Get the files with `scp` from that machine to your machine or from your machine to that machine (`scp {user}@{server-ip}:/{dir}/{dir}/{files}* .`). We use this alot to update our software on a server.

Neither will allow anyone to see your system or your documents/picture folders.